# Convert Nested Dictionary to a graphable format

Tags: json, python-3.x, dictionary

So I'm trying to convert a nested dictionary like:

```
A = {
"root":
    {
        "child1":
        {
            "child11":"hmm",
            "child12":"not_hmm"
        },
        "child2":"hello"
    }
}
```

To this:

```
{
"name":"root",
"children":    [
        {"name":"child1",
         "children" :  
            [{"name":"child11",
              "children":[{"name":"hmm"}]}
            {"name":"child12",
             "children":[{"name":"not_hmm"}]}
            ]

        },
        {"name":"child2",
         "children":[{"name":"hello"}]
       }
    ]
}
```

I need this, since I'm trying to visualize it with this graph drawing template: [Collapsible Tree](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083)

I'm having some trouble creating a recursive method that is capable of this transformation.

Preferably in python3. So far I have:

```
def visit(node, parent=None):
    B = {}
    for k,v in node.items():
        B["name"]=k
        B["children"] = []
        if isinstance(v,dict):
            print("Key value pair is",k,v)
            B["children"].append(visit(v,k))

        new_dict = {}
        new_dict["name"]=v

    return [new_dict]


C = visit(A) # This should have the final result
```

But its wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I would recommend your initial data structure represent each node as following:

{ "name": "label_of_node", "children": [list_of_nodes]} and have the last node have an empty [] as the child.  This will make your parsing algorithm much cleaner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We'll have a function that takes a root (assuming it has only one entry), and returns a dict, as well as a helper function that returns lists of dicts.

```
def convert(d):
    for k, v in d.items():
        return {"name": k, "children": convert_helper(v)}

def convert_helper(d):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        return [{"name": k, "children": convert_helper(v)} for k, v in d.items()]
    else:
        return [{"name": d}]
```

which gives us

```
json.dumps(convert(A), indent=2)

{
  "name": "root",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "child1",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "child11",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "hmm"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "child12",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "not_hmm"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "child2",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "hello"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```